# where can I find random() method in python's random module random.py?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to use a different core random generator in python. On reading random module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html) I found that I have to override existing random,seed,getstate and setstate method. But I can't find random function in random .py module. I am using python 3.4.

Comment: Are you looking for the definition of the `random` method? It is implemented in C.

Comment: Why do you need the source to override it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate slightly? I don't have the reputation to comment yet, but when you say 'different core random generator' are you referring to changing the underlying structure? Python uses a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) as the core generator, which is robust and efficient.

In terms of just generating a random number, you can really just use

```
import random
my_random_number_between_0_and_1 = random.random()
my_random_number_between_0_and_1 # print out your new random number
```

You can also use `random.seed()` and if you do not pass in a seed, the current system time is used, which is pseudorandom as well.

I hope some of this helps! Please let me know if not. Apologies for not understanding entirely.

Comment: hi actually I am trying to use counter based core generator like random123

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the docs say:

> **Class `Random`** can also be subclassed if you want to use a different basic generator of your own devising: in that case, override the `random()`, `seed()`, `getstate()`, and `setstate()` methods. Optionally, a new generator can supply a getrandbits() method — this allows randrange() to produce selections over an arbitrarily large range.

This class is, as noted in the comments, implemented in C.  GVR wrote a [translation in py 3.2](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32/Lib/random.py) that is not maintained but that you can use for reference regarding syntax, arguments, etc.  An exemplary random function can be found on `class SystemRandom`.